# Obfuscate Password as soon as user exits EditBox

Tags: android

How can password be non-obfuscated until user leaves the EditBox, and then obfuscated afterward? I want the user to be able to see the password as they are entering it but obfuscate it as soon as they are done and have moved on to other fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `PasswordTransformationManager` class and an `OnFocusChangedListener`.  Try this:

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focused)
    {
        if(focused)
           ((EditText)view).setTransformationMethod(null);
        else
           ((EditText)view).setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    }
});
```

This will essentially be the same as setting the xml attribute `android:password="true"`, but only when EditText does not have focus.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think android has built in functionality to do this, but you could probably do it pretty easily by subclassing TextView and changing the characters in the onFocusChanged method.  Store the password chars in your variable and replace them with dots when the window loses focus.  When it gains focus, get rid of the dots and put the chars back.